# Почему обычный объект в Java называется Bean(боб)?

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, spring-mvc, spring-jpa

> Бин (bean) — это не что иное, как самый обычный объект. Разница лишь в
>   том, что бинами принято называть те объекты, которые управляются
>   Spring-ом и живут внутри его DI-контейнера. © [Habr](https://habr.com/ru/post/334448/)

Почему так сложилось, что такие объекты прозвали "beans" (бобы?) ?

Comment: не обязательно именно  Spring-ом. Бин (bean)  - объект, управление над жизненным циклом которым передано контейнеру. а само название - просто смекалка авторов)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Потому что ***Java*** - это кофе, которое варят из кофейных ***бобов*** (зёрен). Понятие bean в контексте `Java` применимо не только к `Spring`, а вообще к любому объекту. Идеология создания приложений на `Java`, по задумке авторов, должна быть в том, что разработчик создаёт множество *слабосвязанных/независимых* компонентов (**bean'ов**), а потом собирает их в единое приложение (**Java-приложение**).

А вообще, именно такое название в немалой степени связано со смекалкой авторов `Java`.

Answer (score 3):

Название Java было придумано примерно так:

> We had been in the meeting for hours and, while he was drinking a cup of Peet's Java, he picked 'Java' as an example of yet another name that would never work.
>
> Мы сидели на очередной многочасовой встрече, когда он попивая свою чашечку яванского кофе от "Peet's", привел Java как еще один пример, названия, которое никогда не будет работать.

- Он - имеется ввиду [Chris Warth](https://www.goodreads.com/author/show/7406020.Chris_Warth)
- [Peet's Coffee](https://www.peets.com/) - кофейня, где проходил брейнсторминг по именованию языка.
- Java - сленговое (ам.) сорта кофе растущего на острове Ява в Индонезии

*Bean* - боб, кофейное зерно - аллюзия к именованию Java